Monitor HTTP traffic for Azure Web App using Log analytics and KQL query
I have a Azure Web Application in Azure. I have one endpoint :
https://dev-my-app.azurewebsites.net/test
I would like to see all http requests which were done for this endpoint. I have read that I can use Log Analytics Workspace (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-analytics-workspace-overview) in order to achieve it.
I have configured a workspace. I have also created Diagnostic setting which sends "HTTP logs" to the workspace :

After I go to the "Logs" and try to run the query
// Client requests per hour 
// Count of client requests hourly. 
AGCAccessLogs
| summarize AggregatedValue = count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), _ResourceId
| render timechart


I am getting an error as response:

'summarize' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'AGCAccessLogs'
Request id: 1449b704-70bb-4d84-8c00-0d5b086fa637

It looks like AGCAccessLogs table does not exist in my log analytics workspace.
I have also tried to call this query directly from log analytics workspace:

What am I missing in order to make this query work? Is there other way to see the http traffic for my web app?

You have to run this query in log analytics workspace=>logs of your web app, refer Image.

Thats what I did, I will update question with this image

Select the log Analytics workspace you have configured under Diagonostic settings=>select view logs in Search and analyze logs=> run the query. Refer Image 1, Image 2.

thats what I did., there is no other workspace

I can see you are running the query under Web App=>Monitoring=>Logs but you have to run the query in log Analytics workspace which you have configured under Diagnostic setting.

you are correct. I have tired now also to call the query directly from the worskpace, but still no results. I have updated the answer with the screenshot

Run AppServiceHTTPLogs to fetch the Http logs.

Check my answer below for clear steps.

changing query in order to retrieve AppServiceHTTPLogs  works, I am able to find the requests with all details like IP etc

and for information for everyone interested, I dont need to run it from the workspace, it works also from the web app itself like I have shown in one of the images in my question

Follow the below steps to run the query in Logs.
AGCAccessLogs
| summarize AggregatedValue = count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), _ResourceId
| render timechart


Configure the logging under Diagnostic setting to send Azure platform metrics, resource related logs and other activity logs to Azure log Analytics workspace.
Navigate to Azure web App=> Diagnostic Settings= Select the configured Analytics workspace.



It redirects to the below page, select view logs in Search and Analyze logs:



It takes you to Logs page, you can run the query to fetch the required logs.


Workaround 1:
To fetch the Http Logs of your web app, run AppServiceHTTPLogs query:

Workaround 2:
Configure Application Insights for your web app.
Navigate to Azure Web App=> Settings=> Application Insights=> Logs and run the below query to fetch the Http logs:

Thanks @Niels Swimberghe for the query.

requests
| where resultCode == 200


